# How to add multiple sites in nginx on localhost

Tags: server, php, nginx

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and I have just finished installing LEMP on my local machine. I'm having trouble figuring out how to host multiple sites on nginx. For example, I have a site called "test" and it's located in `/var/www/test` -> `index.php`. But when I run the server at: `localhost/test/index.php` it gives me a 404 error Not Found.

I have added and named the file as "test" to both at sites-available and sites-enabled and restarted nginx and it still didn't work. The original was named default but changed it to example.com because I was following the tutorial on how to install LEMP. I even moved the example.com from sites-available and sites-enabled to the desktop to avoid conflict.

This is my sites available code:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/test;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name test;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Also, after the installation of LEMP I tested a quick script just echoing out the `phpinfo();` and it worked, so I know PHP works. I also have PHPmyadmin and that works, too. I think it's a path issue that I am going wrong here. It's obvious that I am a beginner at Ubuntu which is why I am here. Lol

Perhaps the method that I am trying to achieve isn't possible? I would like to have all my sites under this structure: `/var/www/sitenamegoeshere`

Because according to tutorials I've been only seeing structures such as: `/var/www/sitenamegoeshere/public_html`

Any help will be greatly appreciated it! If needed additional information regarding my LEMP setup, definitely ask me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your configuration you should be able to tell the issue yourself:

```
server_name test;
```

You are telling it to only react to the name `test` (so-called "virtual host") but you access it via the name `localhost`. How is that supposed to work?

For your test setup try editing `/etc/hosts` and include a line like this:

```
127.0.0.1 test
```

... restart `nginx` (e.g. `service nginx restart` as `root`) ... and then try to access it again under that name `http://test/index.php` ... should work, unless you forgot to mention some other relevant detail(s).